# How many episodes are included in Dominion invasion's story arc?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

[The "Story arcs" article at Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Story_arcs#Deep_Space_Nine) says that *Dominion invasion* story arc has eight episodes:

- "In the Cards",
- "Call to Arms",
- "A Time to Stand",
- "Rocks and Shoals",
- "Sons and Daughters",
- "Behind the Lines",
- "Favor the Bold",
- "Sacrifice of Angels".

While in [*Background information* section](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sacrifice_of_Angels_(episode)#Background_information) of the last episode mentioned in above list it is clearly explained, that this story arc was four episode long, then turned into five episodes story arc and finally ended up as having six episodes.

There is no list of episodes in the second link, so I have a trouble understanding, from where is this difference coming in? Is there any explanation on this discrepancy in Memory Alpha? How many episodes are officially included in *Dominion invasion* story arc of Star Trek Deep Space Nine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "six episode arc" is not referring to the entire story arc, simply the six episodes made as an organized effort to tell the story of the Dominion War at the beginning of the 6th season. As Ronald D. Moore explains (emphasis mine):

> The initial thinking was that we would end Season 5 on a cliff-hanger
>   with the Federation plunged into war, and **then we would come back
>   and do a multi-episode arc**, and the war would last that long.

The MA article for [A Time to Stand](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/A_Time_to_Stand_(episode)#The_six-episode_arc) contains much more detail on the planning involved.

In short, the "six episode arc" is what production called it, not a description of the actual story arc.

Answer (score 2):

Arguably, that eight-episode list is two arcs. The first two episodes, *In the Cards* and
*Call to Arms*, are the last two episodes of season five, and (if I remember correctly) show the Dominion

> taking over Deep Space Nine.

The remaining six episodes are the first in season six, and pick up the story three months after the events of *Call to Arms*.

As they’re the first episodes of season six, they were probably planned and written some time after the last episodes of season five (I believe the staff of shows like *Deep Space Nine* would have a holiday between seasons), and so they’re kind of separate, even though they’re essentially continuing the story from the end of season five.